# I got the error 'variable has incomplete type 'void'', and I can't find what's wrong

Tags: c++

I had to count the words of a vector and put it in a map that counts the words. Then the function `showFrequencies` has to show/print the map.

```
map<string, int>CountWords(vector<string> words) {

    map<string, int> count;

    for(auto i = words.begin(); i != words.end(); i++) {

        count[*i]++;
    }

    return count;
}

void showFrequencies(CountWords(vector<string> name)) {

    for (map<string, int>::const_iterator it = count.begin(); it != 

count.end(); ++it) {


    cout << it->first << "\t" << it->second;}

}

int main(){

    vector<string> words = {"hello", "you", "hello", "me", "chipolata", "you"};

    showFrequencies(CountWords(words));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void showFrequencies(CountWords(vector<string> name)) {
```

should be

```
void showFrequencies(const map<string, int>& name) {
```